# Why can't I send iMessage directly from my Apple Watch?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

My Apple Watch series 4 has wifi capabilities but when my iPhone is offline I can't send iMessages directly from my watch. If I can't send the message directly from my watch then what is the true purpose of having wifi enabled on the Apple Watch?

If I'm missing some config then Please help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're trying to get something to work, but it's vital that you give us enough info to help you. Unfortunately, we have no idea what you've tried in order to send a message from your Apple Watch? Likewise, we can't tell you if you're missing some configuration if we don't actually know what your *current* settings are? Finally, this site works best when you're asking one question and at present you've asked two. I would edit your post to remove the *purpose of Wi-Fi on Apple Watch* part and to provide the extra info we need.

Comment: Does this Apple Watch have cellular capabilities?